# Angular Change Detection in a Dynamic Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

I am having an issue with change detection in a dynamically added component in Angular.

I have added a link to a complete Plunker below.

The component has two properties (**grid** and **message**), with setters and getters for both properties.

The **grid** property is based on a "type" interface **IGrid**, and **message** is a **string**.
Both **grid** and **message** are added to the component instance when the component is dynamically created and added to the parent component.

Setters for both **grid** and **message** call a function called **consolelog**.

Based on changes to their respective inputs, change detection for both **grid** and **message** seem to be working.

The issue i am having is that the **consolelog** function is being correctly called in the **message** setter, however the **consolelog** function is not being called correctly in the **grid** setter.

Template:

```
<div>
  <div><b>grid.pinnedColumnHeaders</b></div> 
  input: 
  <input type="checkbox" 
    name="grid.pinnedColumnHeaders" 
    [(ngModel)]="grid.pinnedColumnHeaders">
</div>
<div>
  value: {{ grid.pinnedColumnHeaders || '[blank]' }}
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <div><b>message:</b></div>
  input: <input type="text" name="message" 
  [(ngModel)]="message">
</div>
<div>
  value: {{ message || '[blank]' }}
</div>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-change-detection-onpush',
  template: `...`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class ChangeDetectionOnPushComponent implements IPage {
    private _message: string;
    private _grid: IGrid;

    ngAfterViewInit() {

    }

    constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    set grid(val: string) {
      this.cdRef.markForCheck();
      this.logconsole();
      this._grid = val;
    }

    get grid() {
      return this._grid;
    }

    set message(val: string) {
      this.cdRef.markForCheck();
      this.logconsole();
      this._message = val;
    }

    get message() {
      return this._message;
    }

   logconsole(){
     console.log('test');
   }
 }
```

Complete Plunker:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/t1xK698tsJDnzS5E?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1

Comment: My guess is that in `[(ngModel)]` you are pointing to a property of a `grid` object, so when it changes - setter is not being called, because the object(link) isn't changing, so setter only calls when when the whole new object being passed through `@Input`. If you need to track changes of `checkbox` add `(change)="handleCheckboxChange($event)"` to your html and declare same method in your component.

Comment: Thanks Maksym! Good idea. I had a similar thought, and that is actually my alternate plan if I cannot get this approach working. My ultimate goal with the approach is to run a function from consolelog that sends the entire grid object to a service where updates to the grid can be accessed globally. I'm also going to have a whole lot of additional properties in addition to pinnedColumnHeaders, so I am trying to find an approach where I can capture all of the changes in one spot.

Answer (score 1):

According to what you said in comments, I have two more guesses about the approach you probably looking for:

1. Is the @ngrx/store approach. (it's well documented)
2. Is to make the `grid` as a private `Subject`(or BehaviorSubject from 'rxjs')
   in your service, and make setter and getter in service.

   ```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

   @Injectable()
     export class MyService{

       private grid: Subject<IGrid> = new Subject<IGrid>();

       getGrid(): Observable<IGrid> {
         return this.grid.asObservable();
       };

       setGrid(values: IGrid): void {
         this.grid.next(values);
       }

   }
   ```

   then in any of your components (note, don't forget to make `unsubscribe` on ngOnDestroy()):

   ```
   export class MyComponent {
     grid: IGrid;
     constructor(private service: Myservice){}

     getGrid(): void {
       this.service.getGrid().subscribe((grid: IGrid) => this.grid = grid);
     }

     setGrid(gridData: IGrid): void {
       this.service.setGrid(gridData);
     }
   }
   ```

Still, in this approach, you have to handle input change as suggested above as ngModel won't call the setter if only a part of an object has changed. But in this case you can be sure that if you make changes in one place all the subscribers will receive the changes.

Comment: Thanks again Maksym! I looked at the store approach previously (ngrx/redux), but that approach was ruled out due to architectural concerns (specifically performance and the need to write reducers). My alternate plan is very close to your Observable implementation above, however, I would be using  a service that emits a change event that other components could hook into.

Comment: @jptrue, what Maksym said in the comments to the question is correct. Change Detection will not fire, because Angular points to the reference of the `grid` object. **Changing the value of a property in the `grid` object (a state change) does not change the reference to the `grid` object and therefore Angular change detection will not fire.**  Both Maksyms, suggestions in this answer are a fine solution to your problem.